# ¿Cómo se grafica el de los mejores valores de los índices de un diccionario?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, diccionarios

Tengo el número de ocurrencias de palabras compartidas en dos cuerpos.

```
repeated_keys = set(c_comments) & set(c_tweets)
data = {key: [c_comments[key], c_tweets[key]] for key in repeated_keys}
```

Intenté hacer el gráfico de estas coincidencias pero éste es indigesto:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['Commentaires','Tweets']).T

# plot grouped bar chart
df.plot(kind="bar")
```

¿Cómo se grafica el 10% de los mejores valores de los índices de un diccionario?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Creo que ya que lo tienes en `Pandas` puedes seguir por ahí. Primero me voy a crear un `DataFrame` tonto *"Dummy"* inventado para poder replicar tu problema:

```
import pandas as pd

vars = [i**2 for i in range(2, 100)]
df_a_histograma = pd.DataFrame(vars, columns=["num_repeticiones"])
df_a_histograma["num_palabra"] = range(2, 100)
df_a_histograma = df_a_histograma.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
df_a_histograma.plot(kind="bar", x="num_palabra")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Genial, ya tengo el mismo problema que tu tienes, he hecho plot de un `DataFrame` y tengo el eje de las `x` colapsado por lo que me quiero quedar con las más relevantes. Yo haría lo siguiente:

1. Ordenaría el `DataFrame` de mayor a menor, esto se puede hacer con el método `.sort_values()` de `Pandas`.
2. Multiplico la longitud por `0.1` (el 10%).
3. Creo la gráfica como tu has hecho.

```
#Ordenamos basandonos en el número de repeticiones de forma descendente
df_a_histograma = df_a_histograma.sort_values(by="num_repeticiones", ascending=False)

#Calculamos cuantas columnas tiene el df
long_df = len(df_a_histograma)

#Sacamos el 10% de las primeras columnas usamos round para no tener un número decimal
df_a_histograma[:round(long_df*0.1)].plot(kind="bar", x="num_palabra")
```

**Salida:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]